# Capturing the next N words and elements

Tags: words

I want to do two things.

1. Starting at point, get the next `N` words and store them in a list.
2. Starting at point, get the next `N` elements (any isolated text sequence) and store them in a list.

Comment: What is an "isolated text sequence" pray? That's almost as clear as "element". Also: one question per question.

Comment: An `Isolated Text Sequence` is any continuous sequence of characters with the ends being either whitespace, beginning of line, end of line, or control characters.

Comment: OK - maybe you can ask your second question as a separate question and add this explanation to the question to begin with.

Comment: Isn't this question already included in your other question here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/74219/105?

Comment: Please pose only one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1. only:

```el
(defun my/word-list (n)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((s (buffer-substring (point) (progn (forward-word n) (point)))))
      (s-split-words s))))
```

This requires that the package [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) be installed. It is available on MELPA.

With the following text and the cursor at the `|' below:

```
This is a test of the |emergency broadcasting system.
```

calling the function with `M-: (my/word-list 3)` returns `("emergency" "broadcasting" "system")`.

The function does no error checking (e.g. if there aren't `n` words after `point`, you get a list of the remaining words and no indication that something is wrong).